# Adding Callout type annotation to iOS PDFTron library

Tags: ios, ipad, pdftron

I am facing an issue wherein the PDFNET framework for iOS is successfully rendering callout type annotation made from other platform. But I am unable to allow users of iOS app to make the same annotation from start.

Comment: Could you be more specific. You can't add a callout at all? Or you add it and it does not appear? Screenshots would probably help.

Comment: I cannot add a callout to the iOS app. I dont know the steps to add a callout. Can you tell me how can we add callout in the sample app provided by PDFTron as I am unable to add callout annotation even in the sample app.

Answer (score 2):

This is a programmatic example of how to create a callout annotation using PDFNet:

```
    let txtannot: PTFreeText = PTFreeText.create(doc.getSDFDoc(), pos: PTPDFRect(x1: 100, y1: 100, x2: 350, y2: 500))
        txtannot.setContentRect(PTPDFRect(x1: 200, y1: 200, x2: 350, y2: 500))
        txtannot.setContents("\n\nSome swift brown fox snatched a gray hare out of the air by freezing it with an angry glare." +
            "\n\nAha!\n\nAnd there was much rejoicing!")
        txtannot.setCalloutLinePoints(withKneePoint: PTPDFPoint(px: 200, py: 300), p2: PTPDFPoint(px: 150, py: 290), p3: PTPDFPoint(px: 110, py: 110))
        txtannot.setBorderStyle(PTBorderStyle(s: e_ptsolid, b_width: 1, b_hr: 10, b_vr: 20), oldStyleOnly: true)
        txtannot.setEndingStyle(e_ptClosedArrow)
        txtannot.setColor(PTColorPt(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: 0), numcomp: 3)
        txtannot.setQuaddingFormat(1)
        first_page.annotPushBack(txtannot)
        txtannot.refreshAppearance()
```

(An Obj-C version can be found in the miscellaneous sample project, or on [PDFTron's website](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/AnnotationTest.m.html).)

If you wish to create a callout annotation interactively, you will need to create a new "tool" to do so. All of PDFNet for iOS's UI widgets and annotation creation/editing methods are part of the open source framework Tools.framework, found in `/Lib/Tools`. By using existing tools as sa guide (which create free text annotations, text markup annotations, fill forms, sign documents, etc.), you can create a new tool for creating callout annotations interactively.

SO discolsure: I work for PDFTron.